# How to resolve WebLogic server BEA-000117 and BEA-101162 errors?

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic

I encounter this error:

```
<BEA-000117> <Received a stale replication request for object ...>
```

I went through the documentation and it says that I need to tune garbage collection. How do I actually tune garbage collection? I thought Java garbage collection is automatic? Or do I actually need to change those JVM memory settings like vmx etc?

For

```
<BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.bea.wsrp.consumer.markup.ReleaseSessionsListener failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.wsrp.consumer.markup.SessionContext.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bea.wsrp.consumer.markup.SessionContext
```

What is the reason of this error? Is this Web Services for Remote Portlets (WSRP) issue? Is there a patch for it? Or I need to go in and modify the listener code for this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the BEA-000117 error

Answer (score 0):

What version of WebLogic Portal are you running? Also, what platform are you running the system on?

The stale requests usually mean either a latency/communication issue between the cluster members or (the somewhat unlikely) case where the session times or the user logs out before it's replicated to the appropriate cluster member.